# Error 400 to access Instagram API using Java

Tags: java, oauth, instagram

I have a simple servlet named Autentica that is responsible to get de code parameter used to know the OAuth token. The API returns to my callback page and thus the servlet named callback is runned. The problem is that I cannot get the token from OAuth because I'm receibing error 400 from server. I'm not expert in programming web and maybe can be a newby error.

Anyone can help-me? Follows the servlet codes and the console results. Tks a lot!

1) Servlet Autentica

```
@WebServlet(name = "autentica", urlPatterns = {"/autentica"})
public class Autentica extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        //API Credentials
        String client_id = "XXXX";
        String client_secret = "YYYY";
        String redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/InstagramAPI/callback";

        //Set Session Variables
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("client_id", client_id);
        session.setAttribute("client_secret", client_secret);
        session.setAttribute("redirect_uri", redirect_uri);

        try {
            //Redirect User to foursquare login page
            String url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=" 
                    + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
                    + "&response_type=code";
            response.sendRedirect(url);
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

2) Servlet Callback

```
@WebServlet(name = "callback", urlPatterns = {"/callback"})
public class Callback extends HttpServlet{

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(req, resp);
    }

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String clientID =(String)session.getAttribute("client_id");
        String clientSecret =(String)session.getAttribute("client_secret");
        String redirectURI =(String)session.getAttribute("redirect_uri");  
        String code = request.getParameter("code");

        String url = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?"
                + "client_id=" + clientID
                + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret
                + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
                + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI
                + "&code="+code;
        getContent(url);
    }

    //Return response after GET Request
    public String getContent(String httpurl){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(httpurl);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String strLine = "";
            String content = "";
            while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                 content = content+strLine;
            }
            in.close();
            System.out.println("DEBUG = "+content);
            return content;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

3) Console

```
INFO: InstagramAPI was successfully deployed in 990 milliseconds.
SEVERE: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXX&client_secret=YYYY&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/InstagramAPI/callback&code=7049a73c0dfe43528115fe1a52ff4e0e
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at Callback.getContent(Callback.java:61)
    at Callback.processRequest(Callback.java:52)
    at Callback.doGet(Callback.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

SEVERE:     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1615)
SEVERE:     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
SEVERE:     at Callback.getContent(Callback.java:61)
SEVERE:     at Callback.processRequest(Callback.java:52)
SEVERE:     at Callback.doGet(Callback.java:29)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
SEVERE:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
SEVERE:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
SEVERE:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
SEVERE:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the URL you are calling. It is not in proper format. Are you able to access same url successively from any browser by just typing in url section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a perfect answer for you [over there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily)!

You have to add something like:

```
String urlParameters = "client_id=" + clientID
            + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret
            + "&grant_type=authorization_code"
            + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectURI
            + "&code="+code;

connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));

DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream ());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

after your `conn.setRequestMethod("POST");`.

Comment: Thank you very much, @jan-gerlinger! Its so useful for me! Tks!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you think there was a correct solution to your problem, you can mark that answer as solution and help other users with the same problem find it faster.

Answer (score 2):

You're sending the data to the access_token URL incorrectly. You need to send the fields in the data of a POST request. Not as part of the URL. The URL should only be "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token" and the rest of the data should be form urlencoded as the data in the POST.

Comment: Sure, @mark-s! A stupid error that made me learn a lot! Thank u very much!